# Rails to do a simple calculations (no saving to database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create an application that will compare similar data in two diffrent tables which are in two diffrent databases (oracle, and MS Access)

I do not need any data saved to the database.

Can Rails do this? Or is this being to bare within Rails?

Thanks

Comment: Rails can certainly do this, however, you will basically have to configure your rails app to use the oracle database as it's database to easily pull data from it.  Querying and comparing data is not a problem for rails, but the trick lies in how you configure your system to communicate with the databases.

Comment: should be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054/any-tips-on-getting-rails-to-run-with-an-access-back-end

Comment: Ty! I appreciate those topics. They seem to point me in the right direction!